# Prove by determinant properties

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[(ax+by,ay+bx,az+bx)(ay+bz,az+bx,ax+by)(az+bx,ax+by,ay+bz)]=(a^3+b^3)[(x,y,z)(y,z,x)(z,x,y)]​ have been trying to solve this but l don't know what to do with a+b.would like to know how to solve this from start.
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
ax+by&ay+bz&az+bx\\
ay+bz&az+bx&ax+by\\
az+bx&ax+by&ay+bz\\
\end{bmatrix}
=(a^3+b^3)
\det\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z\\
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Was the top row meant to be $ax+by,\,ay+bz,\,az+bx$?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE! :D

You can first find some structure in the matrix on LHS
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
ax+by&ay+bz&az+bx\\
ay+bz&az+bx&ax+by\\
az+bx&ax+by&ay+bz\\
\end{bmatrix}
=a
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z\\
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
\end{bmatrix}
+b
\begin{bmatrix}
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
x&y&z\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This express the complex matrix in terms of two simple ones. Note that the 2nd matrix on the right side is just a row / column permute version of the 1st matrix on the right. This relation could be expressed by matrix multiplication by a permuation matrix.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
x&y&z\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z\\
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus our first equation could be written as a matrix decomposition
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
ax+by&ay+bz&az+bx\\
ay+bz&az+bx&ax+by\\
az+bx&ax+by&ay+bz\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z\\
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\left(a
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
+b
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
=\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z\\
y&z&x\\
z&x&y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&0&b\\
b&a&0\\
0&b&a\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then using the property of determinant $\det (AB) = \det A\det B$ then you get your desired equation. :)
$$
\det \begin{bmatrix}
a&0&b\\
b&a&0\\
0&b&a\\
\end{bmatrix} = (a^3+b^3)
$$